# How to initialize an int array within a struct within another struct arrya?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

```
struct customFunction {
    int id;
    int numOfSubfunctions;
    int subfunctions[];
};

const customFunction supportedFunctions[] = {
    {
        0x01,
        1,
        {
            0x01
        }
    },
    {
        0x02,
        2,
        {
            0x01,
            0x02
        }
    }
    ...
};
```

The `supportedFunctions` array will be used to check whether a specific function is supported in the future and used to identify which function to use, etc.

Currently, I have this error showing up:

> too many initializers for ‘int [0]’

which points to

```
{
    0x01
}
```

For any function, there may be `0 - n` numbers of subfunctions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will never work.  Multiple `customFunction` elements in the same array *cannot* have different sizes for their `subfunctions[]` members.  Array elements must be the same size.

If the `customFunction` elements need to have `subfunctions[]` arrays of different sizes, you will have to store the actual arrays elsewhere in memory and then point to them, eg:

```
struct customFunction {
    int id;
    int numOfSubfunctions;
    const int *subfunctions;
};

const int subfunctions_1[] = {
    0x01
};

const int subfunctions_2[] = {
    0x01,
    0x02
};

const customFunction supportedFunctions[] = {
    {
        0x01,
        1,
        subfunctions_1
    },
    {
        0x02,
        2,
        subfunctions_2
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: And is this cache friendly?

Comment: Does it matter? It is the only option to do what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!